# Integral of $\int \frac{\cos x+\sin 2x}{\sin x}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to find the integral of $$\int \frac{\cos x+\sin 2x}{\sin x}$$

$$\int \frac{\cos x}{\sin x} + \int \frac{\sin 2x}{\sin x}$$

$$\int  \tan x + \int \frac{\sin 2x}{\sin x}$$

I think I am suppose to have the integral of tanx memorized so I will put that to the side for now.

$$\int \frac{\sin 2x}{\sin x}$$

I do not know what to do with this since I can't make a u subsitution or anything else so I will just randomly use the double angle identity I have memorized.

$$\int \frac{2\sin x\cos x}{\sin x}$$

$$\int 2\cos x$$

$$2 \int \cos x$$

$$2\sin x + \int  \tan x$$

$$2\sin x + \ln|\sec x| + c$$

This is of course wrong.

Comment: $\cos x\over \sin x$ is $\cot x$, not $\tan x$.

Comment: I think you are missing a few $dx$'s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that $$\dfrac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)} = \cot(x)$$ and not $\tan(x)$. An easier way to do $\int \dfrac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)} dx$ is to do as follows. Hence, $$I = \int \dfrac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)} dx.$$ Set $\sin(x) = t$, then we get $\cos(x) dx = dt$. Hence, $$I = \int\dfrac{dt}{t} = \log(t) + C = \log(\lvert \sin(x) \rvert) + C$$
Hence, your answer is $$2 \sin(x) + \log(\lvert \sin(x) \rvert) + C$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

Recall the chain rule $$g(f(x))'=g'(f(x))\cdot f'(x)$$
and note that
$$\frac{\cos x }{\sin x} =\frac{f'(x) }{f(x)} =\frac{f'(x) }{f(x)}=\frac{1 }{f(x)}\cdot f'(x)$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}
\int \frac{\cos x}{\sin x}\mathrm dx +2 \int \frac{\sin x\cos x}{\sin x}\mathrm dx &= \int \cot x\,\mathrm dx+2\int \cos x\,\mathrm dx\\
&= \ln|\sin x|+2\sin x+c
\end{align}$$

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.SE. Thank you for your answer! I've edited it to use MathJax. For some basic information about writing maths at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latexhelp/notation).